# Do Dragonborns get resistance?

Tags: dnd-4e, damage-resistance, racial-traits

Do Dragonborn get resists based on what element they choose as their breath weapon? I know there are some paragon paths that give something close to this but I'm wondering if they get it as a racial trait.

- I'm wanting to make a Dragonborn Paladin to Kord and I'm wanting to know if i chose Lightning as the breath weapon if it gives me resists to Lightning.

I've googled about this and I've found nothing but some people mixing up some 4e and 3.5e rules.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

**No**

Dragonborn, the race, get no resists by default.

That is not to say that they get no resists however. If a dragonborn takes the:

- [Argentum Alliance](http://www.wizards.com/dndinsider/compendium/paragonpath.aspx?id=636) paragon path, they get cold damage added to their breath weapon, and resist cold,
- [Storm dragon](http://www.wizards.com/dndinsider/compendium/paragonpath.aspx?id=535) paragon path(requiring lightning as a breath weapon) gets resist thunder and lightning,
- [Wyrmtouched Amulet](http://www.wizards.com/dndinsider/compendium/item.aspx?id=3104): resist 10/15/20 to their breath type.